# Multiple servers for hosting

Tags: nameserver

Would like to know is it possible to have sites hosted in a sever and have a separate nameservers in a different network. For example,

Sites hosted in site5 and have nameservers one in site 5 network and the other in 123systems.
Is it possible? If so where do I need to update the information. At the domain registrar or at the place where my site is hosted.

Please advice. I planning to have my site hosted in a vps and have a separate nameservers for redundancy. I think I will register my domain name with namecheap.

How can I proceed to do. Is there any good example of a site or videos link. Do I need to inform anyone in particular regarding my nameservers.

Some authority or anything.

Comment: Start grabbing a book about how the internet works. DNS, IP etc. - this is a fundamental "I have no idea what DNS is" type of question.

Comment: @TomTom I understand how a DNS works. The reason I ask such question, My client told me that, their shared hosting account proider told them that they cant use private nameservers. They have to use the nameservers provided by the hosting company.

Comment: @TomTom Since I am not a server expert, I had doubts and wanted to clarify this. I am mere developer who is going into hosting a solution for my clients.

Comment: @user1571494 If their provider tells them this, then maybe you should ask the provider *why* what's the case...

Comment: @user1571494 Well, "we do not care" is the only valid answer then as per FAQ. Only people here allowed that have beginner knowledge and do server administration in a professional capacity. Check the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. You need to update secondary DNS info if your domain provider supports it. Once you have updated that then if site5 nameservers go down 123site nameservers take over.

More info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

I suggest reading it :)

Comment: Better to use our own secondary dns or use services such as dnsmadeeasy.com

Comment: If we are into product recommendations - these days I do my DNS stuff with cloudflare.... and can then also use their nice web caching infrastructure on top (for free). Makes a LOT of stuff easier (i.e. google analytics integration, which works without doing anythin on the website itself).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.  I do it (`dig ns.teaparty.net` and `dig ns2.teaparty.net`; note how wildly different the IP addresses are).

The `whois` needs to know about all of your servers; that is usually updated via your registrar.

The DNS service on the primary needs to know about the offsite secondary, so it advises it to do zone xfers on update, and permits the xfer requests when they come.

The DNS service on the offsite secondary needs to know about the primary, so it expects advice-of-updates from the appropriate address(es).

Comment: so do you advice to have private secondary nameservers or go dor paid services such as dnsmadeeasy.com

Comment: how will they comunicate with each other

Comment: Technically there is no difference; it is a business decision (do you want the expense and complexity of running your own, and do you mind the loss of control when you outsource it?).  And I agree with TomTom (above), your question is beginning to betray significant ignorance of how the DNS works.  You need to understand the basics before posting to ServerFault.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I have mentioned and replied to TomTom regarding why I asked suched question above. any advice on it.